# How to use the Groovyscript result to make a request with different ID parametersin SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have JSON Response

> {
>      "maxResults": 50,
>      "total": 3,
>      "items":    [
>               {
>            "id": "1",
>            "key": "AC11"
>         },
>               {
>            "id": "2",
>            "key": "BC22"
>         },
>               {
>            "id": "3",
>            "key": "CC33"
>         }
>                 ]
>   }

Here is Groovyscript to get ID value from JSON response

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
String items, id
int AccSeqNumInt
def responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("GetID").getPropertyValue("response")
def Response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
id = Response.items.id
```

Groovyscript result

> Script-result:[1, 2, 3]

Also I have POST request with ID value which are substituted from request parameters

> http://test.run.org/secure/CreateItems.jspa?inline=true&decorator=dialog&id=1

Question:

How to make automation POST request with different ID parameters from groovyscript results?

Comment: Do you need to test by using one id at time i.e., fire 3 requests with different id each call?

Comment: Yea, using one id at time i.e.,  3 requests with different id each call

Comment: All of this is necessary to fix the working log. Working time is 8 hours.

In my POST Request 2 params:
1. ID - id of the task
2. timelogged - time spent for this task.
 
If as a result of the script comes 5 id, then using the script 8 randomly divide by 5, for example id1 - timelogged=2,id2 - timelogged=2,id3 - timelogged=2,id4 - timelogged=1,id5 - timelogged=1 the total amount of timelogged should be 8. And so on

Then alternately for each id and its timelogged using script to do POST Request

Comment: if you need I can draw the road map

Comment: Is this what you mean?
1. Get script result [1,2,3]
2. Run service with POST request with ID = 1, the next request with ID = 2 and the next with ID = 3

Comment: Yes. But for each request, necessary to use the timelogged parameter,which can be calculated randomly. For example, i have 3 tasks,respectively there are 3 IDs.My working time=8 hours.8\3=for ID1 timelogged parameter=2,for ID2 timelogged parameter=4,for ID3 timelogged parameter=2
1. Get script result [1,2,3]
2. Run service with POST request with ID=1 where timelogged parameter=2.next
Run service with POST request with ID=2 where timelogged parameter=4.next
Run service with POST request with ID=3 where timelogged parameter=2
NOTE:the sum of timelogged parameters should not be more than 8